# How read(get) css style value of a server-side div in code behind(not set)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

i want to get 'display' css value of a server side div!
the code below does not work :

```
    if (div.Style["display"] == "none")
    {
        div.Style.Add("display", "table-row");
    }
```

how can i get that value in c#?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are these inline styles or found in CSS styles?

Comment: in head element of aspx form i added display css of that div -> none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you are trying to do on the server side. The Style property only works with the inline styling. Consider client side JavaScript.

`<div id="div" runat="server" style="display: none;">Foo</div>`

Answer (score 2):

<del>div.Attributes["style"].Add("display", "table-row")</del>

Use this:

```
if (div.Attributes["style"].ToString().Contains("display:none;")) 
{ div.Attributes.Add("style", "display:table-row"); }
```

or try

```
div.Attributes["CLASS"].ToString().Contains("CLASS_NAME")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that but I guess you are applying some logic to do something if your div is visible or not(dispay:none or not). If that's the case why not use an html input element and toggle its value as per need?

Answer (score 1):

better solution:

**HTML**

```
<div id="divID" runat="server" style="display:none;"></div>
```

**C#**

```
if(divID.Style.Value.ToLower() == "display:none;")
{
   divID.Style.Add("display", "table-row");
}
```